# Question about Identity Resolution in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery Table which contains two columns:

1. masterIdentity -> a string that identifies a user
2. secondIdentity -> another string that identifies the same user, the masterIdentity identifies

Those values do not have a 1:1 relationship. Instead, every masterIdentity can be referenced as a secondIdentity by another masterIdentity.
This would result in the following table:

[Values I am starting with]

[image: 1]

What I am now trying to achieve is querying the table in such a way that I only have masterIdentities left that are not referenced as a secondIdentity by any other masterIdentity.
Those "final" masterIdentities should reference every other secondIdentity that is either directly or indirectly referenced by the "final" masterIdentity.
The query should return the following values:

[The Values I want to return]

[image: 2]

How am I supposed to query the database if there is not a fixed limit on how many levels "deep" this cross-referencing can go?

I hope you understand what I mean!
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: x1 is not part of masteridentity in your sample data and still showed up in your desired ouput for xx3 , is that what you want  or your sample data is not showing all possible scenarios?

Comment: I just corrected the sample data. There was a type which did not make sense. If you could possibly take a look at it now. The sample data is now correct :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly :

```
select t1.masteridentity , t3.masteridentity as secondidentity
from ( 
   select t1.masteridentity frp, yourtable t1
   where not exists (select 1 from yourtable t2 where t1.masteridentity = t2.secondidentity)
) as t1
cross join (select distinct masteridentity from yourtable t3 where t3  <>  t1.masteridentity) as t3 on 1 = 1
```

Comment: @AlexanderVoit maybe as keyword is a must , see updated answer